# Convert unicode to list of tuples

Tags: python, list, unicode, tuples

I have Unicode :-

```
x = [[u'customer', u'=', 1], [u'parent_id', u'=', False], [u'user_id', u'=', 1059]] <type 'unicode'>

print type(x)
<type 'unicode'>
```

I need to convert this as a list of tuples like `[('customer', '=', 1),('parent_id', '=', False)]`

Please help me

Comment: The code you are posting above cannot be reproduced... (https://repl.it/HmBa/0). It prints `<type 'list'>`

Comment: I have the "x" which is a unicode string

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
my_uni_list = [[u'customer', u'=', 1], [u'parent_id', u'=', False], [u'user_id', u'=', 1059]]
result = [tuple(x) for x in my_uni_list]
```

Comment: @Hoodiee What do you mean by *key*?

Answer (score 1):

Just `iterate` if you are using python 3.x and use `tuple()`

```
>>> L = [[u'customer', u'=', 1], [u'parent_id', u'=', False], [u'user_id', u'=', 1059]] <type 'unicode'>
>>> [tuple(i) for i in L]
[('customer', '=', 1), ('parent_id', '=', False), ('user_id', '=', 1059)]
```

Comment: do `tuple(i) ... ` since OP wants tuples

Comment: I have the unicode and need to convert as list of tuples

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean:

```
>>> x = u"[[u'customer', u'=', 1], [u'parent_id', u'=', False], [u'user_id', u'=', 1059]]"
>>> print type(x)
<type 'unicode'>
```

You can use `eval(x)` to translate `x` to a `list`.

```
>>> l = eval(x)
>>> print type(l)
<type 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = [[u'customer', u'=', 1], [u'parent_id', u'=', False], [u'user_id', u'=', 1059]]
>>> y = map(lambda t: tuple(t),x)
>>> y
[(u'customer', u'=', 1), (u'parent_id', u'=', False), (u'user_id', u'=', 1059)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 2:

```
>>> x = u"[[u'customer', u'=', 1], [u'parent_id', u'=', False], [u'user_id', u'=', 1059]]"
>>> type(x)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> y=[tuple(t) for t in eval(x)]
>>> y
[(u'customer', u'=', 1), (u'parent_id', u'=', False), (u'user_id', u'=', 1059)]
>>> type(y)
<type 'list'>
>>> type(y[0])
<type 'tuple'>
>>>

>>> map(lambda t: tuple(t),eval(x))
[(u'customer', u'=', 1), (u'parent_id', u'=', False), (u'user_id', u'=', 1059)]
>>>
```

Python 3:

```
>>> x = u"[[u'customer', u'=', 1], [u'parent_id', u'=', False], [u'user_id', u'=', 1059]]"
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
>>> [tuple(t) for t in eval(x)]
[('customer', '=', 1), ('parent_id', '=', False), ('user_id', '=', 1059)]
>>>
```